# Save a charfield column with prefix and primary key combined in django model?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

i created a model "PurchaseRequest". the pk is autocreated. Now, i created a charfield column which would store a value like "PR# + pk" during save process.

```
 def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    self.pr_number = 'PR #' + str(self.id)
    super(PurchaseRequest, self).save()
```

BUT, it returns PR#None . once i edit and save it , it returns correct answer as obviously it fetches id now.

Comment: Well, it's the database that allocates the pk, so it can't be present until *after* you save. So you'll need to save twice, once to get the pk and then again to update the number.

Comment: i got that. what could be the possible solution??

Comment: I just said. Save (by calling super), then set the PR, then save by calling super again.

Comment: Thank you. solved.  and sorry! u had to answer you twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first save the object then set the PR field and then save again.

You can do something like this:

```
 def save(self, **kwargs):
     super(PurchaseRequest, self).save(**kwargs)
     self.pr_number = 'PR #' + str(self.id)
     super(PurchaseRequest, self).save(**kwargs)
```